# Back Transforming Rates in Poisson GLM with Box and Cox Transformation

Tags: generalized-linear-model, data-transformation, poisson-distribution, fitting, count-data

Suppose I have fitted a Poisson GLM to model rates as follows:

```
> fit.1=glm(response~X1+X2+ offset(log(population)),family=poisson,data=...)
```

I can get the estimated rates by using two new values for X1 and X2 and population=1 as follows:

```
>new.data=data.frame(X1=new.X1,X2=new.X2,population=1)
>estimated.rates=predict(fit.1,newdata=new.data,type="response")
```

Following Subsection 13.4.5 in [Introduction to Linear Regression Analysis, 5th Edition](http://ca.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470542810.html), I then double check the Deviance Residuals using `qqnorm` and found that they are not even approximately normally distributed. So to revise my model, I used a box and cox transformation (lambda) to improve the model and fitted a new quasi-Poisson model:

```
> fit.2=glm(I(response^lambda)~X1+X2+ offset(log(population)),family=quasipoisson,data=...)
```

I can again estimate the rates similarly as before:

```
> estimated.rates.2=predict(fit.2,newdata=new.data,type="response")
```

The `estimated.rates.2` is on the scale of the transformed response (using the box and cox transformation).

Is it possible to back transform the rates `estimated.rates.2` into the original scale (i.e. similar to `estimated.rates`)?

Comment: Why do you need the residuals to be normal?

Comment: We need to check the it and correct it if they are not. See e.g. the reference I gave [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92394/checking-residuals-for-normality-in-generalised-linear-models/92413#92413).

Comment: The quote you give is not a reason to transform. It's an observation that is sometimes but not always true.

Comment: I don't understand it. Can you explain more?

Comment: I checked the residuals and found that they are not normal. So I used Box cox transformation. BTW, this is not my question, my question is something else.

Comment: Your question is based on a misapprehension. There's no need for them to be normal.

Comment: That's not correct Glen. This is why I gave a reference. In that book, they have fitted a poisson GLM (together with other glm models) and performed a qqplot to double check the normality. Like any other lm, we need to check it as well.

Comment: A Poisson GLM assumes that data is conditionally Poisson, not normal. Why would anyone be surprised to discover non-normality for something assumed non-normal? You said (of checking normality) "We need to check the it and correct it if they are not." -- I'm sorry, but as a general statement that's simply false. Residuals (any of the kinds in common use) in GLMs can be plainly non-normal when nothing whatever is wrong with the model. I repeat what I said: there's no need for them to be normal. It can be useful to look at the plot, but non-normality is not *of itself* an indication of a problem.